# position:fixed not working for navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep my navigation fixed while i try to scroll down but setting `position:fixed;` is not helping. Here is my navigation:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="second.html">Register</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="second.html">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {  
    position:relative;  
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: inline;     
    background-color: #FF9933;
    height:90px;
    width: 1400px;  
    background-image: url(G:/wallpapers/nav3.jpg);    
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 130%;
    }

#nav ul {   
    list-style: none;   
    padding: 0;
    height:800px;
    width:300px;    
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
}    

#nav ul li { 
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold; 
    left:900px;
} 

#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    left:900px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have searched out other websites. `position:fixed` is working for them but not for me. This is what they are using:

```
.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#body_div {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 273px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav_bar {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

//the below css are for the links, not needed for sticky nav
.nav_links {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_links li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.nav_links li a {
  padding: 0 15.5px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //change the integers below to match the height of your upper dive, which I called
  //banner.  Just add a 1 to the last number.  console.log($(window).scrollTop())
  //to figure out what the scroll position is when exactly you want to fix the nav
  //bar or div or whatever.  I stuck in the console.log for you.  Just remove when
  //you know the position.
  $(window).scroll(function () { 

    console.log($(window).scrollTop());

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 550) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 551) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
  });
});
 </script>
 <body>
 <div id="banner">
  <h2>put what you want here</h2>
  <p>just adjust javascript size to match this window</p>
</div>

  <nav id='nav_bar'>
    <ul class='nav_links'>
      <li><a href="isha.html">Sign In</a></li>
      <li><a href="isha.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="isha.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I'm not able to understand how to apply this to my code. Is there some problem with me keeping position in navigation relative?

Comment: *"I am trying to keep my navigation fixed.."* -- but then you are assigning `position:relative;` to your `#nav` ??? Did you check your rules' precedence?

Comment: It would really help if you provide a jsfiddle or any other on-line editor.

Comment: Setting `position: relative;` on your nav element will — last time I checked — position it relative... not fixed.

Comment: @Abhitalks  i need to keep it relative to the background so that it is placed at right place wrt background.

Comment: Please add a working code snippet, so we can see whats going on, or else all we can do is guess.

Comment: @ishaarora95: What do you mean by *"relative to background"*?? Besides that, you have all sorts of problems with your CSS. What's with so many `left` properties splattered across?? What does `text-align: inline;` mean?? Why are you using a class `navbar-fixed-top` which doesn't exist?? Why are you not clearing the floats?? Forget positioning and jQuery. You need to first learn basics of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue is that you're trying to tell us, but here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLccjLr9/1/

```
#nav {  
    position:fixed;  
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: inline;     
    background-color: #FF9933;
    height:90px;
    width: 1400px;  
    background-image: url(G:/wallpapers/nav3.jpg);    
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 130%;
}
```

Note I've also added some `margin-top` to the `#banner` `<div>` so that it displays immediately below the nav. I've also made the `<body>` a 1000px high to demonstrate that it works...

Answer (score 0):

your spell mistake css class name `navbar-fixed` & jquery class name `navbar-fixed-top`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function () { 

    console.log($(window).scrollTop());

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 365) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 366) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1x6qLLp1/